# How can I get child component?

Tags: angular

I want to get child component inside a parent component

there is no idea,so I need help.

like this code

```html
<parent><child></child></parent>
```

I hope get Child in Parent's component.

I hope get Child in Parent's component.
like this stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5j7vq , there is no 'ng-content' in parent compenent, but I want to get inside component 、html 、template。

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to render the child component inside the parent?

Comment: like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5j7vq , there is no 'ng-content' in parent compenent, but I want to get inside component 、html 、template。

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) from the official documentation.

Parent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-parent',
template: `
<app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>
`,
styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent{
parentMessage = "message from parent"
constructor() { }
}
```

Child

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-child',
template: `
Say {{ message }}
`,
styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

@Input() childMessage: string;

constructor() { }

}
```

Don't forget to declare the components in your module file.

Edited :-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    I'm parent
    <ng-content></ng-content>//do this..
  `,
  styles: [ '' ]
})
```

Comment: like this stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5j7vq , there is no 'ng-content' in parent compenent, but I want to get inside component 、html 、template。

Comment: You are trying to render the components passed to parent tag from the app.component.ts. This will never render child component unless you render the content passed in the parent component. Add the tag <ng-content></ng-content> in your parent's template.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `<child></child>`inside your parent component html file, so that child will be inside parent component

Comment: like this stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5j7vq , there is no 'ng-content' in parent compenent, but I want to get inside component 、html 、template。

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data inside a child component inside parent, then use @Output property or @ViewChild().Please refer `[Component Interaction][1]`

if you want to just call child component in parent, then add in parent.html:

```
<child-selector></child-selector>
```

Comment: like this stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5j7vq , there is no 'ng-content' in parent compenent, but I want to get inside component 、html 、template。

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear but if you're trying to render the child component inside your parent component you can use `<ng-content></ng-content>`.  When you add markup between the parent selector, `ng-content` will be replace with the content.

I've provided a stackblitz demo at the bottom.

#### parent.component.html

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

#### another.component.ts

```
<parent>
    <h1>Content will render in parent.</h1>
</parent
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgchqe
>
> https://medium.com/@joshblf/wtf-is-ng-content-8382b2a664e1

Comment: like this stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5j7vq , there is no 'ng-content' in parent compenent, but I want to get inside component 、html 、template。

Comment: @user10091238 In that stackblitz, if you add `<ng-content></ng-content>`  to the parent template it should work.  The content you put between `<app-parent><h3>More content</h3></app-parent>`  will be swapped with the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag.  See the stackblitz in the bottom of my answer